# Angular Deployment Issue - Netlify Environment Variables with Dotenv and Environment.ts

Tags: angular, environment-variables, apollo-client, netlify, dotenv

I'm facing challenges in accessing Netlify environment variables in my Angular application, having attempted both dotenv and the environment.ts approaches.

Here's a snippet from my environment.ts file:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: 'API_URL',
  hasuraAdminSecret: 'HASURA_ADMIN_SECRET',
};
```

In the graphql.module.ts service file, I've used dotenv to access the environment variables:

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import 'dotenv/config';

const uri = process.env.API_URL || 'default-api-url';
const adminSecret = process.env.HASURA_ADMIN_SECRET || 'default-admin-secret';
```

However, I'm encountering issues with both approaches. With dotenv, there's a polyfill error, and the traditional environment.ts method isn't displaying the actual values from Netlify environment variables. Console.log outputs show only variable names, not the values.

I think that the Netlify environment variables are correctly set up. I'm hoping someone would be able to help me solve this issue.  If you have insights or guidance on using dotenv or environment.ts in Angular v16 on Netlify, your help would be greatly appreciated.FYI I'm running Apollo and GraphQl with the dependencies below

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.8.1",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.8.1",
    "apollo-angular": "^5.0.2",
    "apollo-angular-link-http": "^1.11.0",
    "apollo-link-ws": "^1.0.20",
    "auto-i18n": "^1.0.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^8.0.1",
    "google-translate-api": "^2.3.0",
    "graphql": "^15.8.0",
    "keycloak-angular": "^14.1.0",
    "keycloak-js": "^22.0.4",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.19",
    "terser": "^5.22.0",
    "translate": "^2.0.2",
    "translate-google": "^1.5.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^16.0.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
```

Thank you!